# How to fix Facebook integration with firebase and googleMobile Plugin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Stuck with the facebook unity plugin integration. I have been working on it since yesterday and did not find any workaround.

I am using facebook-unity-sdk-7.15.1 although I have also tried the previous version of facebook plugin that didn't work as well.

I am building a gradle build.
My project includes the following plugins
FireBase-6.0.0
GoogleMobileAds-7.41
GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.64

Every time Build failed with an error which is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object   at Google.VersionHandler.InvokeMethod (System.Type
>   type, System.Object objectInstance, System.String methodName,
>   System.Object[] args,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2[TKey,TValue] namedArgs)
>   [0x00054] in
>   Z:\tmp\tmp.7eOCFUaXh7\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\VersionHandler\src\VersionHandler.cs:506
>   at Google.VersionHandler.InvokeStaticMethod (System.Type type,
>   System.String methodName, System.Object[] args,
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] namedArgs)
>   [0x00000] in
>   Z:\tmp\tmp.7eOCFUaXh7\third_party\unity\unity_jar_resolver\source\VersionHandler\src\VersionHandler.cs:481
>   at
>   Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver.setupDependencies
>   () [0x00034] in <1e648b4081db4625b06f95d668cd2dd4>:0    at
>   Facebook.Unity.Editor.AndroidSupportLibraryResolver..cctor ()
>   [0x00000] in <1e648b4081db4625b06f95d668cd2dd4>:0 
>   UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes()

Comment: Probably related to https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/235 and https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/issues/209 ?

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed this problem couple of days ago.There was some missing files of facebook. Just paste these following file in plugin and  we are all set to go.

```
com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1.aar
com.android.support.appcompat-v7-25.3.1.aar
com.android.support.cardview-v7-25.3.1.aar
com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-25.3.1.a
```

rr